# How to manage element precedence in JavaFX2?

Tags: user-interface, javafx-2, operator-precedence

Given this code:

```
@Override
public void start(final Stage stage)
{
    final StackPane root = new StackPane();
    final Region r1 =  new Region(), r2 = new Region(), r3 = new Region();

    r1.setMaxSize(400, 400);
    r1.setStyle("-fx-background-color: yellow");
    StackPane.setAlignment(r1, Pos.TOP_LEFT);

    r2.setMaxSize(400, 400);
    r2.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black");
    StackPane.setAlignment(r2, Pos.TOP_RIGHT);

    r3.setMaxSize(400, 400);
    r3.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue");
    StackPane.setAlignment(r3, Pos.BOTTOM_CENTER);

    root.getChildren().addAll(r1, r2 ,r3);

    final Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 600);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

The output  is the following:

[image]

Is there any easy way to control element precedence, without removing and re-adding all the elements that follow in the correct order? What I want to do, in this particular case, is make the element with the `yellow` background to overlay the other two, thus resulting in this:

[image]

The `Scene Builder` can move elements with `CTRL+([|])`. The only way that I can think of currently though, when it comes to doing this in code, is getting the children of the root element and doing pairs of remove/add in the correct order. Is there any other way, like, maybe, some property that manages overlay priority? Thank you.

Comment: Items are ordered in order of containment in collection (getChildren())

Comment: so the only way to control the precedence is through removing and re-adding in the particular order that would give the desired overlay combination?

Comment: Seems, yes (if somebody will not remember anything better). You can add/remove; FXCollections.sort() - is also a way of changing order.

Comment: Alexander, please make your comment an answer, so it can't be accepted and upvoted. Removing/adding elements is a perfectly correct way of manipulating list order.